# Both variables algebraic/ both transcendental?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, transcendental-numbers

> Suppose $X\subset \Bbb Z_{<0}$, and $a=\sum_{n\in X} 2^n$ is algebraic, then is $b=\sum_{n\in X}3^n$ also algebraic? (To clarify, what I mean is: does it hold for **all** such $X$?)

We know that $a$ and $b$ must either both be rational or both irrational, simply by noting the fact that under any integer base, rational numbers coincide exactly with recurring decimals. But what about being algebraic/transcendental? Is there anything we can say about it? By the way I'm no algebraist (not even a smart math student) so apologies for not being able to proceed any deeper.

Comment: I feel there does not exist $X$ so that both sums are algebraic irrational. It would be something to behold. There are countably many such $X$ for which the first sum is algebraic irrational. Same for the second sum. Out of uncountably many subsets. Highly unlikely to have a match. Now, one can explicltely produce lots of $X$ for which both sums are provably transcendental ( say Liouville type numbers).

Comment: To add onto this, specifically, as long as $X$ is sufficiently sparse, both are transcendental.

Comment: Also, this might be a stupid question, but can we even find $X$ such that $b$ is irrational but algebraic?

Comment: @orangeskid I totally agree with your comment except for the first claim.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut this is a deep question, and I just realised all possible $b$'s will form something like a Cantor set, won't they?

Comment: @Vim Yes. I believe all possible $b$s form 
the standard Cantor set but with each term divided by $2$.

Comment: @Carl Schildkraut: I should revise that claim. Extremely probably there are no $X$ for which the sum is algebraic irrational. So the question would have a resounding No answer! The reason is that the ternary expansion of an algebraic irrational looks like a "random" sequence of $0$, $1$ and $2$. So $2$ must necessarily appear at some point.

Comment: @orangeskid Just to clarify, this is a reason why none _should_ exist, not a proof that none do exist, right?

Comment: @Carl Schildkraut: Correct. However,  I doubt even the statement that there should appear infinitely many $2$'s in the ternary expansion of a particular algebraic irrational has a proof.

Comment: Let $f(z) = \sum_{n =0}^\infty 1_{n \in X} z^n$. I wonder if the OP meant $P(f(1/2)) = Q(f(1/3)) = 0$ for two different polynomials $P,Q \in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, or if they meant $P= Q$ or say $P = Q+\alpha$.

Comment: @Carl Schildkraut: Now a statement that does not contradict right away this closely held belief would be this: Consider the ternary expansion of an irrational algebraic ( the binary would not work)  and apply a permutation of the values of the digits  ( say substitute $0\to 1\to 2 \to 0$). Now you can ask whether you can still get an algebraic number. The "randomness" tells you nothing, as for it the values $0$, $1$, $2$ are like symbols. But again, I highly doubt you would ever get again an algebraic number.

Comment: @reuns what do you mean by $P=Q=0$? What I mean is just whether $f(1/2)$ and $f(1/3)$ are simultaneously algebraic, or simultaneously transcendental.

Comment: @Vim If there is an algebraic relation for both $f(1/2),f(1/3)$ I wonder if it has good chances to come from $f$ itself, hence $P,Q$ are related.

Comment: I think this is somehow reducible to the case $X=\Bbb Z_{<0}$.

Comment: @marshalcraft that would make them both integers